# How to generate multiple file paths and save them into a excel with python

Tags: python, excel, string, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I want to generate hundreds of file paths in python and save them into an excel file. Each path should save in a separate row and paths vary just by one value. I am not sure how to iterate it through a for loop.

Here is my try:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i in range (4):
    worksheet.write('A%d', '/home/exx/Documents/Input/%d/2.mp4', %(i)))  
    workbook.close()
```

Output is excel file should be like below:

```
/home/exx/Documents/Input/0/2.mp4
/home/exx/Documents/Input/1/2.mp4
/home/exx/Documents/Input/2/2.mp4
/home/exx/Documents/Input/3/2.mp4
```

Comment: Not sure about the excel part, but try `'/home/exx/Documents/Input/%d/2.mp4' % (i)` or `f'/home/exx/Documents/Input/{i}/2.mp4'`  for the path string part. EDIT: To make it more clear, remove the comma before `% (i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here:

- workbook should be closed outside of the for loop
- if you want to start generation from 0 but write the first line in row number one in the excel file you should do i+1 in the row count
- there shouldn't be a space after a range keyword

The fixed snipped should look like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i in range(4):
    worksheet.write(f'A{i+1}', f'/home/exx/Documents/Input/{i}/2.mp4')

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filepaths.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#column parameter is set to zero (0), because you want all the entries to be on the first column
for i in range(4):
    worksheet.write(i, 0,  f'/home/exx/Documents/Input/{i}/2.mp4')

workbook.close()
```